# Clicking a button refreshes a page (unintended) with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to automate an upload of a file to my github repo.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Eliran\Desktop\chromedriver')
browser.get('https://github.com/login')

username=browser.find_element_by_id('login_field')
username.send_keys(myemail)

password=browser.find_element_by_id('password')
password.send_keys(mypassword)

sign_in_btn=browser.find_element_by_name('commit')
sign_in_btn.click()

browser.get('https://github.com/DevEliran/DevEliran.github.io/upload/master') #pathing immidiately to "upload files" in my repo
commit=browser.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/main/div[2]/div/form/button")[0] # commit button
upload=browser.find_element_by_class_name('manual-file-chooser')#manually uploading my file
upload.send_keys(myfilepath)
commit.click()
```

after `commit.click()` the page refreshes and present an error : "Add some files to include in this commit."

I have double checked every element.
Has anyone came across a same problem  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you check if the file path actually exists ?

```
if (!os.path.exists(myfilepath)):
    print(myfilepath + ' doesnt exist')
else:
    print(myfilepath + ' exists')
    upload.send_keys(myfilepath)
    commit.click()
```

if file exists, there's a possibility that its being sent to incorrect element. Try sending path first to this xpath and then wait for it to upload and then
find and click on the commit element.

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys(myfilepath)

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 90)
men_menu = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='files']//td[@class='name']")))

browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Commit')]").click()
```

Comment: It exists for sure . I can see the file uploading to GitHub before the refresh occurs

Comment: Thank you very much ! it is working now . 
So if I understood it right my problem was that the file hasn't finished loading while i was already trying to click commit ?

Comment: That is correct. You can manually upload once and see how much time it takes and adjust the wait time according to your file size..